# When remove admin-approved form template from Central admin , IIS will reset?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

When remove admin-approved form template from Central admin , IIS will reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't. You have the option to "quiesce" the form so currently active users don't get dumped but IIS shouldn't be reset. The form should just stop showing from then on.

Comment: Where that option , when I click remove from central admin , I do not see such option.